# How to compare date type in Sql to javascript date

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

I have a javascript date string in ISO format, e.g

```
dtStart = 2016-09-05T07:00:00.000Z
```

and I want to compare it in an SQL query to a column that is label DateTimeCollected. An example of DateTimeCollected could be `2014-06-27T00:00:00.000Z`.

How could I comare these two dates in SQL by using something like

```
DateTimeCollected >= ${dtStart}
```

in the query where dtStart is a string. I am using MSsql if that is of any help.

Comment: You can pass this string representation to sql as a char variable and cast it to datetime, datetime2 or datetimeoffset. This is a string format Sql server should always cast correctly to datetime.

Comment: What SQL type is DateTimeCollected ?

Comment: @Alex K. datetime

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeCollected >= CONVERT(${dtStart}, @stringDate, 126)
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should thicken it with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing the values in Sql, you should be able to simply do this:

```
DateTimeCollected >= CAST(@DateTimeString As DateTime).
```

Assuming `@DateTimeString` is a char(23) variable containing a string representation of a datetime value following the ISO8601 format (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`)

In fact, you can also do this without the casting, because Sql server will implicitly cast the string into a datetime data type. However, I beleive it's better to use explicit casting since it's more readable.

As I wrote in the comment, SQL Server should always cast the correct date if it's passed as a string following the ISO8601 format.